# range search complexity of R tree and R* tree

Tags: data-structures, complexity-theory, spatial-query, r-tree

What is the range search complexity for R tree and R* Tree? I understand the process of range search: similar to a DFS search, it visits each node and if a node's bounding box intersects the target range, then include the node in the result set. More precisely, we also need to consider the branch-and-bound strategy it uses: if a parent node doesn't intersect with the target, then we don't visit its children nodes. Then the complexity should be smaller than O(n), where n is the number of nodes. I really don't know how to calculate the number of nodes given the number of leaves(or data points). 
Could anybody give me an explanation here? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, the worst case must be at least O(n) if your range is [-∞;∞] in every dimension. It may be as bad as O(n log n) then because of the tree.

Assuming the answer is a single entry, the average case probably is O(log n) - only few paths through the tree need to be followed (if you have little enough overlap).

It is log to the base of your page size. So it will usually not exceed 5, because you never want trees with more than say 1000^5=10^15 objects.

For all practical purposes, assume the runtime complexity is simply the answer set size O(s). Select 2% of your data it takes twice as long as 1%.

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.